# Custom file filter (maven-resource-plugin)

Tags: java, maven, resources, filtering, maven-resources-plugin

I`ve got some (html) files which eventually have to be included to a WAR file. 
The files look like:

```
<html>
..
<!-- marker_id_start -->
.. html mark-up I want to keep...
<!-- marker_id_end -->
..
</html>
```

I`d like to transform content of each file cutting off everything before *marker_id_start* and after *marker_id_end* so the result file would look like:

```
<!-- marker_id_start -->
.. html mark-up I want to keep...
<!-- marker_id_end -->
```

or even just like

```
.. html mark-up I want to keep...
```

The transformation is part of war assembly process, so I thought I could use maven resource plugin with a custom filter.
Obviously I would need to configure marker ids but I`m not sure how to do that and how to make these custom config options visible in my filter.

The only documentation I`ve found is this: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/custom-resource-filters.html but it does not say much, only very basic things.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Filtering isn't about removing parts of the file, but replacing tokens by a specific value at built-time. Why do you want to do this?

Comment: I guess removing is replacing with empty strings ;)

Answer (score 0):

According to [Apache Maven Resources Plugin / Filtering](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) filtering applies to:

> variables, denoted by the `${...}` delimiters

Have a look at the [`transform`](http://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/transform-mojo.html) goal of the [XML Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/):

> - [`xml:transform`](http://www.mojohaus.org/xml-maven-plugin/transform-mojo.html) transforms XML files by applying XSLT stylesheets.